# Crash in Firebase SDK

Tags: ios, firebase

I recently installed Firebase for crash reports in my iOS app and I see a lot of crashes happening in their framework. I could reproduce it a couple of times and it's always when I launch the application. After the crash, I open again the app and it works. I haven't managed a way of reproduce it 100% of the times yet.

The crash is not very helpful as there's no information or anything about it.

The issue is happening here
`-[GULNetworkURLSession sessionIDFromAsyncPOSTRequest:completionHandler:]`

Has anyone seen this as well? Any idea of what can be happening?

Comment: You should file a bug report and include all the relevant details.  Stack Overflow probably won't be too helpful for you here.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Are you using `Crash Reporting` still? It's not supported anymore. If yes, do you have the option to upgrade/change to the `Crashlytics`?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1964